# Como posso pegar itens não visualizados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Uso o seguinte **select** para pegar os items já vistos:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM views b, news a WHERE a.status = 'true' AND a.id = b.id_news AND b.ip = '$ip' ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 6");
```

Onde: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`.

Estruturas de tabela:

- views

  id | id_news | ip
- news

  id | titulo | texto | status

Pretendo pegar por um select todos as notícias não vistas, ou seja, se eu não visualizei, não tem meu ip relacionado com o id de uma notícia.

Eu sempre alimento a tabela views quando um usuário entra na notícia, lá é inserido o id da notícia e o ip do usuário.

Como posso fazer este tal select para pegar apenas notícias não visualizadas? Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Já tentou usar o operador **<>** ou **!=** ? 

`$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM views b, news a WHERE a.status = 'true' AND a.id = b.id_news AND b.ip != '$ip' ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 6");`

Comment: É só usar a query acima selecione todas as nótícias que não contiverem o ip do usúario.

Comment: Eu usei sim, porém, não retorna nada, pois só tem registros do meu ip na tabela "views".

Comment: E como eu disse, a tabela "views" só registra quando alguém acessa a notícia. Acho que uma lógica pra isso seria verificar se meu ip existe relacionado a notícia, porém na query eu não sei fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Estudando um pouco mais sobre sql consegui chegar ao resultado esperado. Espero ajudar outras pessoas, caso tenham uma dúvida relacionada. Aqui está o resultado final da query:

```
$sql = self::query("SELECT * FROM news a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM views b WHERE b.id_news = a.id AND b.ip = '$ip') ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 6");
```